# How to make Dovecot maildir format emails be gziped using zlib

Tags: email, compression, gzip, dovecot, ubuntu-18.10

I activate compression plugin by set following on Dovecot:

```
# /etc/dovecot/conf.d/20-imap.conf
(...)
protocol imap {
  mail_plugins = $mail_plugins zlib
}

# /etc/dovecot/conf.d/90-plugin.conf
(...)
plugin {
  zlib_save_level = 6
  zlib_save = gz
}
```

Restarted but maildir file seem not compressed :

```
# file  1578950990.12797_0.host.xxx.xxx:2,
1578950990.12797_0.host.xxx.xxx:2,: SMTP mail, ASCII text, with very long lines
```

1. there is an error to use gzip compression on email ?
2. how to compress existing emails from server ?

Found : https://gist.github.com/cviebrock/e37f80a3223dfee19051c936c5ebe509

Server : dovecot 2.2.33.2 Ubuntu 18LTS

Thanks for help

Comment: Related [Serverfault post](https://serverfault.com/questions/1007996/compress-old-emails-with-dovecot)

Answer (score 2):

You have made dovecot capable to **read** compressed files in maildir directory.

As I understand you need separate tweaks to compress (old) uncompressed messages.

---

https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/zlib_plugin/#compression

> You’ll probably want to use some cronjob to compress old mails. […]

Comment: Example of ["cronable" script](https://github.com/George-NG/dovecot-maildir-compress)